# Button share image in java application swing

Tags: java, facebook, swing, twitter, share

I'm working in java swing application of retouching images, and I want add button share in social network. I have no idea how I call interface of Facebook, twitter or others to do that.

If some one can help me?

Comment: I think your going to need to explain that further. I don't see how you could "share" your application on a social network

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean that you want a user to be able to use your application to log into Facebook or Twitter and post an image.  In that case, you will need to:

1. [Register your application](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/) with Facebook.
2. Download a Facebook API like http://restfb.com.
3. Integrate the API into your application.  See the Publishing a Photo sample on the main page.

Similarly, for Twitter, you will need to use a Java API like [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html).